# How to restrict uploading of certain media files to Sitecore?

Tags: media-library

I am new to Sitecore and not sure how to restrict certain files from being uploaded to the Media Library.
Let's say we do not want users to upload pdf files to Sitecore; how would you do that?

Write some codes or could we just make a Sitecore patching file?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Sitecore's Upload Filter](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/secure_the_file_upload_functionality#_The_upload_filter).

It's a Sitecore package you install from through the Installation Wizard which adds a config file and a pipeline processor that can limit file uploads to the Media Library by extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could use third-party modules, one that I know of is [`Media Library Policeman`](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Media_Library_Policeman.aspx)

Module description taken from Marketplace:

> The Media Library Policeman module helps you to restrict what files that may and may not be placed in a specific folder along with restrictions for how large the files can be.

However, it is quite old so you'll have to test it first and you may need to download the source code and update it yourself.